# SparkDeploySchedulerBackend Error: Application has been killed. All masters are unresponsive

Tags: apache-spark

While I'm starting Spark shell:

```
bin>./spark-shell
```

I get the following error :

```
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Data nucleus jars on classpath
Welcome to SPARK VERSION 1.3.0
Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.7.0_75)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
15/05/10 12:12:21 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/05/10 12:12:21 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

I have installed spark by follow below link :- http://www.philchen.com/2015/02/16/how-to-install-apache-spark-and-cassandra-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: I am using 32bit system with 3GB RAM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should supply your Spark Cluster's Master URL when start a `spark-shell`

At least:

```
bin/spark-shell --master spark://master-ip:7077
```

All the options make up a long list and you can find the suitable ones yourself:

```
bin/spark-shell --help
```

Comment: please update your question according to your real usage, hard to guess

Comment: use 'hostname' command to find host and then use command    "bin/spark-shell --master spark://your-host-name:7077"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are running this in standalone/local mode.
Run your spark shell with following line. That indicates you are using all the available cores of your master which is local machine.

`bin/spark-shell --master local[*]`

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Answer (score 1):

You also need to start spark master and slave before giving spark-submit command

```
start-master.sh
start-slave.sh spark://spark:7077
```

then use

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your log files for "permission denied" errors... It may happens that your client service doesn't have the proper authority to access your Master folders.